# DrawerLayout not functioning and blocks not related widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-framelayout, drawerlayout

I havd an `Activity` which has a `TextView` and i wanted to add a navigation drawer to that `Activity`. So I changed my `XML` and implemented `DrawerLayout`.

After implementing the `DrawerLayout` it simply does not functioning(meaning it don't open) and the `FrameLayout` implemented within the `DrawerLayout` blocks the not related to the `DrawerLayout` `TextView` text.

**drawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.dl.master.lyrics.lyricsmaster.LyricsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_tv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Try me! NOW"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<!--
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_tv_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
-->
```

The `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout` is the not related `DrawerLayout` widgets which cannot be seen. And the other `TextView` is the navigation drawer `TextView`. I know the navigation drawer widget has to have `android:layout_gravity="start"` property but it apparently has no layout parent so AS does not let me write it.

When running the `Activity` i see the text "Try it NOW" of the navigation drawer `TextView` and that's all.

**DrawerActivity.java**:

public class LyricsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView text;

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

    this.initializeViews();

    this.actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(LyricsActivity.this,this.drawerLayout,
            null,R.string.open_drawer_description,R.string.close_drawer_description);
    this.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    //this.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    this.text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Tags"));
}

/**
 * Initialize all my views.
 *
 */
public void initializeViews()
{
    this.lyrics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_tv_id);
    this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_id);
}
```

I read all the documentation and a lot of SO post and nothing helped me nor addressed this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` determines which `View`s to use as a drawers by their `layout_gravity` attribute. Simply add this attribute to your `TextView` with the appropriate value. For example:

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:text="Try me! NOW"
/>
```

Comment: I wrote I can't. The `XML` file somehow can't recognize that `TextView` as a child view of the `DrawerLayout`. But thanks for the answer. Any other idea?

Comment: How do you mean? Are you getting an error? The rest of the layout looks OK.

Comment: It's just doesn't prompted went i start to write `android:layout_g`. And all the other properties does prompted.

Comment: Your layout is fine. If your IDE is giving you problems, try cleaning and rebuilding the project. Also, I don't know which IDE you're using, but in mine, I don't type the `android:` prefix for it to autocomplete; just the attribute name, like `layout_g...`.

Comment: AS. I just added `android:layout_gravity="start"` and the drawer still not working but the text is not shown in the `Activity`.

Comment: How are you determining that the drawer's not working? You've not completed the toggle setup, so you'll have to pull the drawer out manually, by dragging it.

Comment: What else is there for me to complete the toggle setup? OK it is working(the drawer) but still I can see the `TextView` which in the `LinearLayout`

Comment: 1) Call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in `onCreate()`. 2) Remove the `null` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call. 3) And call `actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()` at the end of your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "but still I can see the `TextView` which in the `LinearLayout`". You should be able to see that. It's in the main content.

Comment: I got it. I just removed the `LinearLayout`. Thanks for the help mate.